# I can't redirect to another website in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, web, redirect, hyperlink, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't redirect to another website in ASP.NET Core MVC. I want to have a link that redirect to another website but it's not working for me.

I tried to put the link (e.g. `https://www.twitter.com/`) simply in the `href="..."` of my `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/mclaren/" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
```

Is there any reason why it doesn't work? I have to display every socials (that are in my database in the table Contact) of every contact, so I need this to work and to work efficiently.

Thank you!

Comment: What page do you get? A page for login?

Comment: As I haven't implemented Identity yet, it returns me to the /Home/Index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try different approach :-
Create a Action method in you controller

```
public IActionResult RedirectExample()
{
    return Redirect("https://www.instagram.com/mclaren/");
}
```

and in razor page

```
<a href="/Home/RedirectExample" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
```

Comment: It did work! Thank you very much. Still doesn't unserstand how the first method that I've done didn't work but I will stick with what your doing until then!